# auto importing python classes in flask shell not working as expected

Tags: python, flask

So I have a flask app structured in this manner

```
calvin % tree -L 3 .
.
├── README
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── env.pyc
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── alembic.ini
├── api.sublime-project
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── agencies
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── models.pyc
│   ├── agents
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── api.pyc
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── constants.pyc
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── decorators.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── districts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── helpers.pyc
│   ├── middleware.py
│   ├── middleware.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── properties
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   └── viewings
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── models.pyc
│       ├── views.py
│       └── views.pyc
├── config.py
├── config.pyc
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── shell.py
```

I am setting up my shell so that it auto-imports all the classes located in the `models.py` files when I execute `./manage.py shell`

And this is the script in `manage.py` that is intended to achieve that (reference flask-script docs)

```
def _make_context():
    from app import models
    return dict(app=app, db=db, models=models)  # TODO: this is not working appropriately
manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=_make_context))
```

In my app/models.py, I have import statements from every module, "agencies", "auth" etc etc.

However, when I enter my shell environment, I have to access my classes as `models.Users` instead of directly `Users`, which is not what I am expecting.  How do I auto-import everything so that I can access the classes directly?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simplified solution that assumes you're using SQLAlchemy (db.Model). If not, you should only need to change the issubclass if-statement to match your appropriate check of what to import.

```
from app import db, create_app
import app.models as models
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell 
app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)

def make_shell_context():
    return_dict = {}
    # grab everything we can possibly import from the models module
    module_importables = dir(models)
    for importable in module_importables:
        # if it isn't a class, it'll throw a TypeError exception that importable is not a class
        try:
            # we only want our SQLAlchemy models
            if issubclass(getattr(models,importable),db.Model):
                return_dict[importable] = getattr(models,importable)
        except TypeError as inst:
            pass
    return_dict['app'] = app
    return_dict['db'] = db
    return return_dict

manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
from app import models
```

You can do:

```
from app.models import *
```

This will import all classes,variables from models. Note: It is usually not recommended to import * but in this case, it could work for you. Ideally, you should do something like:

```
from app.models import Users, ...and so on
```

Comment: Nope this does not work as I have to pass the imported module containing the classes I want to the Shell class' module argument.

Comment: Pass in to the models argument, not module.